# How to find a node inside other DOM node

Tags: jquery

In native .js i could use

```
element.querySelector('.some');
```

But how can i find some node inside other node in jquery, like

```
$('.element').???
```

Answer (score 1):

By using [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/):

```
$('.element .some');
```

Or by using `.find()`:

```
 $('.element').find('.some');
```

Comment: i have this `element` like `$(this)`, so it will be right enough to use .find() method ?

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use descendant selectors (almost exactly like CSS, plus a few jQuery-specific extensions). See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/:

```
$('.element .anotherelement ul');
```

2) Another variant is to use a selector and supply the context in which to find it. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/:

```
$('.anotherelement', $(".element"));
```

This restricts to the search for "anotherelement" to the context of the jQuery object returned by selecting ".element".

3) You can use various of the jQuery search methods as documented here: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

The most commonly used are generally `.find()` and `.filter()`, e.g:

```
$( ".element" ).find( "ul" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

This will set the background colour of all `<ul>` elements within `.element` to red.